# Cannot compile a haskell project using cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal

I'm trying to compile a haskell project using cabal, but when I execute 
`cabal configure` appears:

```
Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: MM-0.1.0.0 (user goal)
[__1] next goal: base (dependency of MM)
[__1] rejecting: base-4.12.0.0/installed-4.1... (conflict: MM => base>=4.9 &&
<4.10)
[__1] fail (backjumping, conflict set: MM, base)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: MM, base
Trying configure anyway.
Configuring MM-0.1.0.0...
cabal: Encountered missing dependencies:
base ==4.9.*, cassava ==0.5.*, containers ==0.5.*, time ==1.6.*
```

I tried using `cabal new-build` and `cabal install --only-dependencies` but it still doesn´t work.

Answer (score 1):

The program you're installing needs `base` 4.9.x.x, which means GHC 8.0.x. Your GHC is too new. Downgrade to 8.0.2, or look for a newer version of the program you're trying to install.